# Scrolling window with packery Draggabilly library

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using "packery Draggabilly library" for Drag and Drop object.
Problem is that I have so many element on page, if I want to move first element to the last then I am unable to scroll the window with dragging element, is it possible to handle this situation with "Draggabilly"?. If yes then how can I do this. Please suggest.

Here i attaching my code snippet.

Code file from where i calling my custom "dragEnd" Method:

```
 my_makeEditable: function (element) {
                var $itemElems, mainGrid = $('#main-grid');
                // get item elements, jQuery-ify them
                if (typeof element === 'undefined') {
                    if (MyEditorMain.my_isEditingMode()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $itemElems = $(mainGrid.packery('getItemElements'));
                } else {
                    $itemElems = $(element);
                }
                $itemElems.each(function (i, itemElem) {
                    var $itemElem = $(itemElem);
                    if($itemElem.hasClass("my-block-sponsor-small")) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var draggie = new Draggabilly(itemElem, {
                        'handle': '.my-move-icon'
                    });
                    if ($itemElem.data("draggabillified") !== true) {
                        mainGrid.packery('bindMyDraggabillyEvents', draggie);
                        $itemElem.data("draggabillified", true);
                    }
                    if(!$itemElem.hasClass("my-position-locked")) {
                        $itemElem.resizable({'handles': 'e, s, se'});
                    }
                });
                mainGrid.packery('on', 'dragItemPositioned', MyEditorHandlers.itemWasDragged);
                mainGrid.data("is-editing", 'true');
                var editIcons = $itemElems.children('.my-block .my-tool-icon');
                editIcons.removeClass("hidden");
                editIcons.trigger('poi.set-point-location');
            }


and this my custom function to handle drag event:
Packery.prototype.bindMyDraggabillyEvents = function (draggie) {
     "use strict";

    var pckryInstance = this;

    draggie.on('dragStart', this.handleDraggabilly.dragStart);
    draggie.on('dragMove', this.handleDraggabilly.dragMove);
    draggie.on('dragEnd', function () {
        var draggieInstance = this,
            draggedItem = pckryInstance.getItem(draggieInstance.element),
            spaces,
            i,
            x,
            y;

        pckryInstance.layout();

        spaces = pckryInstance.packer.spaces;

        x = draggedItem.placeRect.x;
        y = draggedItem.placeRect.y;

        for (i = 0; i < spaces.length; i++) {
            if ((x === spaces[i].x) &&  // the block is in the same column as the space
                    (draggedItem.placeRect.width === spaces[i].width) && // the block is the same width as the space
                    (y > spaces[i].y) // the block is lower on the y-axis than the space begins (meaning there is open
                                      // space above the block).
                    ) {
                if ((spaces[i].height === Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) || (y === (spaces[i].y + spaces[i].height))) {
                    draggedItem.positionPlaceRect(x, spaces[i].y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        pckryInstance.handleDraggabilly.dragEnd.apply(draggieInstance);
    });
};
```

Comment: please show your code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am using packery Draggabilly library, by getting help from  "http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html#jquery-ui-draggable". I just want to scroll window automatically when element dragging if the web page is to big.

Comment: And do you want from us to download the code from that site, create an example page, write a working code for your problem and post it here? If yes, then try this at http://weareworkingforfreeforyou.com This is not how Stack Overflow works. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, i have posted my code snippet. The code file is too long so i posted only important part of the code. Is it possible to scroll window if i want to drop, dragged element at the bottom of page when page size is too large. -Thank you